# Showing that two spans of sets of functions are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, trigonometry, vector-spaces

In $V=C(ℝ)$, let $$S_1 = \{\sin(x), \cos(x), \sin^2(x), \cos^2(x)\}$$ 
and 
$$S_2 = \{1, \sin(2x), \cos(2x)\}.$$ 
Do these two sets span the same vector space?
Hence, is $\operatorname{span}(S_1)= \operatorname{span}(S_2)$ true?

Attempt:

I'm quite sure that to show two spans are equal I must show each is contained in the other (can be written as a combination of the other.

So I think I have to use trig identities like $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$ to show that these functions can be written as linear combinations of the others but am unsure. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Do I have to exclusively use functions from Span $S_2$ to write functions in $S_1$ and vice-versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$\sin2x\in S_1.$$

Id est, there are reals $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ for which for all value of $x$ holds:
$$\sin2x=a\sin{x}+b\cos{x}+c\sin^2x+d\cos^2x.$$
Now, take $x=0$, $x=\pi$, $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

For $x=0$ we get $b+d=0$, for $x=\pi$ we get $-b+d=0$, which gives $b=d=0$.

For $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we get $a+c=0$ and for $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ we get $-a+c=0$, which gives $a=c=0$.

Thus, $\sin2x=0$ for all value of $x$, which is contradiction, which says that the answer is "no".

Comment: Why do you take those particular values and how does a=b=c=d=0 show the answer is no? I'm still a bit confused but thank you so far

Comment: @Mathstatsstudent I added something. See now.

Comment: I understand it now, thank you!

Comment: @Mathstatsstudent You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to show the result, is by comparison of dimensions.
It holds

$$\dim[\operatorname{span}(S_1)]=4$$
$$\dim[\operatorname{span}(S_2)]=3$$

To see this, you need to show linear independence of the vectors of $S_1$, as well as the linear independence of the vectors of $S_2$. And that can be done using the method Michael stated.